# Any more examples of ここ as a time reference?

Tags: grammar, time

I recently heard the phrases
ここ最近 ("somewhat lately"/"these recent days") and
ここ二日ぐらい（"these past 2 days or so").

I had never heard ここ used in this way before, and I was wondering if anyone knew of other phrases or examples which use ここ to mark time in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually a common usage of 「ここ」.  Off the top of my head, we say the following quite often.

・「ここのところ」(informally,「ここんとこ」) = "these days", "recently", etc.

・「ここしばらく」 ＝ "for some time now", "for some time to come", etc.

・「ここ一番{いちばん}」　＝　"at the critical moment”

・「ここ（ぞ）という時{とき}」 = "at a (good) chance", "at an important moment", etc.

Comment: Great examples, thanks. Btw are you a native speaker?

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, there's ここのところ or its casual version ここんとこ, which means essentially the same as 最近. That's two place words making a time expression(!)

[Goo Dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/77801/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%81%93/) gives this time-related meaning as ここ's third definition, and mentions that it doesn't necessarily refer to the recent past, but can also refer to the near future - essentially any period of time that's adjacent to the present. The phrase it uses an example is ここ数年, which can refer to "the last few years" or "the next few years" depending on context.

Comment: Just putting two Tangorin explanations here too:

1. these last (followed by a duration noun and a past sentence: time period before the present time of the speaker)
2. these next ... (followed by a duration noun and a non past sentence: time period after the present time of the speaker);  the next ...;

大雨のためここ２ヶ月間毎日野菜の値段が上がっている。 = The heavy rainfall has caused vegetable prices to rise daily for the last two months.
僕はここ３年ばかりあの人に会わない。=  I haven't seen him for about three years.

Comment: @ CrisCM I'm not sure I get why ばかり is in there

Comment: @ Ben_Roffey now that you mention it I've heard ここのとろこ many times. But I've never heard ここ referring to future events (as far as I know).

Comment: @kandyman For example, （自分たちの事業も）ここ数年が勝負だ: The next couple of years are crucial (for our business)